# react media query with styled component

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, styled-components

I am using react-responsive media query along with styled component. Based on media query, I have to set two different styles. the "div" is not rendering with "iDiv" or "rDiv". definition should be "Div", then only it works on top of "div". In that case I cannot define a two different styles for same div. Please suggest me, how do I approach this ?

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import Login from '../components/user/login'
    import styled from 'styled-components'
    import MediaQuery from 'react-responsive';

    const iDiv = styled.div`
      width: 70%;
      height: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 30%;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
    `
    const rDiv = styled.div`
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 7%;
        top: 40%;
    `

    export default class LoginContainer extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <MediaQuery query="(min-device-width: 1224px)">
              <iDiv> /* not working, expected would be "Div" */
                <Login />
              </iDiv>
            </MediaQuery>
            <MediaQuery query="(max-device-width: 1224px)">
              <rDiv>
                <Login />
              </rDiv>
            </MediaQuery> 
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: why not just define the media query in your styled components definition?

Comment: yes. then it'll be everywhere. it will be easy to identify where people works in at component level using media query component.

Comment: It's the same difference essentially. You're putting a media query for this component and in other components. If it's a react component that does the query or if the styled component you're defining here. Both are defined in a single component.

Answer (score 0):

the approach you made -even if it works- is not the best practice
the reason is that react will render the same children components of the styled component over and over for each time you are using it.
on top of that imagin the number of lines of count when you have to use it for multiple devices not just two. it will be a mess.

instead, here is a better approach for using media query
firstly we define the screen size for each device:

```js
const size = {
  mobile: "320px",
  tablet: "768px",
  laptop: "1024px",
  desktop: "2560px",
}
```

then we use css imported from styled-components to address media queries in relevant constants for each device

```js
export const mobile = (inner) => css`
  @media (max-width: ${size.mobile}) {
    ${inner};
  }
`;

export const tablet= (inner) => css`
  @media (max-width: ${size.tablet}) {
    ${inner};
  }
`;
export const desktop= (inner) => css`
  @media (max-width: ${size.desktop}) {
    ${inner};
  }
`;
export const laptop= (inner) => css`
  @media (max-width: ${size.laptop}) {
    ${inner};
  }
`;
```

now lets say you are creating a styled div and you want to use media queries

```
const StyledDiv= styled.div`

 /* ...css */

   ${mobile(css`
     width:300px;
      /* ...css */
   `)};

   ${tablet(css`
     width:500px;
      /* ...css */
   `)};

    /*... and so on */
`;
```

inside `return` just use it like that:
`<StyledDiv>....</StyledDiv>`